# multiply all columns in data frame in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I need to multiply all columns in a data frame with each other. As an example, I need to achieve the following:

```
mydata$C1_2<-mydata$sic1*mydata$sic2
```

but for all my columns with values going from 1 to 733 (sic1, sic2, sic3,..., sic733).

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
for(i in 1:733){
for(j in 1:733){
mydata$C[i]_[j]<-mydata$sic[i]*mydata$sic[j]
}
}
```

Could you help me? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `apply(mydata, 2, function(x) x * mydata)`

Comment: Do you really want a dataframe with 537289 columns?

Comment: @Georgery Yes, unfortunately that's exactly what I need

Comment: How many rows do you have? Are you sure the result will even fit in memory? This really seems like an XY problem - why do you think you need this?

Comment: @patL it gives me back an error message that it cannot allocate vector of size 60.9Mb

Comment: Try increase your memory limit: `memory.limit(size = memory.limit() * someScalar)`

Comment: @Gregor I have almost 10,000 rows, I need to estimate a cosine index for the 733 categories and for multiple periods in time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the question if you really want what you think you want, I feel like this could help:

```
df <- data.frame(
    a = 1:4
    , b = 1:4
    , c = 4:1
)

multiplyColumns <- function(name1, name2, df){
    df[, name1] * df[, name2]
}

combinations <- expand.grid(names(df), names(df), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names4result <- paste(combinations[,1], combinations[,2], sep = "_")

result <- as.data.frame(mapply(multiplyColumns, combinations[,1],     combinations[,2], MoreArgs = list(df = df)))
names(result) <- names4result
result
```

Comment: Thanks @Georgery it looks like the right approach, I just need to allocate more memory now.